# Планирующийся и планируемый — в чём семантическое различие?

Tags: семантика, глаголы, причастия

В чём семантическое различие между **планирующийся** и **планируемый**? И есть ли единое различие для всех подобных пар вообще? (Возвратный глагол в форме действительного причастия и прямой глагол в форме страдательного причастия.)

По сути значение одно — "который в данный момент кто-то планирует».

**Дополнение**

Согласно [Розенталю](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/61.htm), значения совпадают и если не возникает двузначности или корявого смысла, то можно и так и так:

> §176, п. 2. Действительные причастия настоящего времени на -щийся- совпадают в значении со страдательными причастиями на -мый: состав, отправляющийся (отправляемый) на восток; рукав, пришивающийся (пришиваемый) к пройме; товар, выставляющийся (выставляемый) на витрину; но в сочетаниях типа коровы, отправляющиеся (отправляемые) на убой; реакция, вызывающаяся (вызывавмая) медицинским препаратом следует предпочесть страдательное причастие (см. также §175, п. 4).
>
> §175, п. 4. При использовании глаголов на -ся следует учитывать возможность совпадения у них двух значений – страдательного и возвратного, что может породить двузначность, например: Сюда собираются дети, потерявшиеся на улице (сами приходят или их собирают?). В подобных случаях необходима соответствующая нужному смыслу правка; ср.:
> а)       Сюда приходят дети...;
> б)      Сюда собирают детей...
> Ср. также: «Деталь бросается в ванну» (вместо Деталь бросают в ванну). В технической литературе формы на -ся целесообразно употреблять в тех случаях, когда на первый план выступает самое действие независимо от его производителя, например: Дверь открывается автоматически. Если же с понятием действия связано представление о его производителе, иногда неопределенном, то правильнее употреблять формы без -ся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет какой-то "общей разницы" между глаголами во всех таких парах.
Вы (возможно, вслед за граммой) взяли не самые характерные, пригодные для обобщений пары. Но даже в них ваше разделение по семантической нагрузке весьма условно и более связано с личным восприятием. Я с большим трудом просматриваю разницу между "планируемый" и "планирующийся" в большинстве конструкций, даже если исключить творительный субъекта.

Давайте по пунктам.
~1. *Планируемая к производству модель* vs *Планирующаяся к производству модель* - вы видите разницу, кроме, возможно, стилистической?!
~2. *Планируемая руководством к производству модель* vs *Планирующаяся руководством к производству модель* - тут вообще даже что-то усмотреть сложно.
~3.

> "Планирующийся проект скоро будет запущен" — свойством проекта
>   является то, что он в данный момент планируется.
>
> "Планируемый проект скоро будет запущен" — просто указание на то, что
>   это проект, который планируют.

Не просматриваю такого. Просто первое звучит немного тяжеловесно на фоне второго.

~4. И самое главное. Возьмем совсем уж свободный от нежелательных ассоциаций пример.

Умывающийся (мылом) подросток - умываемый (мылом) подросток.

Разница есть. Но совсем не та, что вы декларировали.

Теперь по сути вопроса.
У возвратных глаголов выделяют несколько семантитических типов - по семантике употребления показателя возвратности.
В корпусной грамматике выделяют аж 11 таких типов.

> Показатель -ся имеет следующие употребления:
>
> 1) рефлексивное (см. п.2.1): папа бреется;
>
> 2) пассивное (см. п.2.2): дом строится;
>
> 3) декаузативное (см. п.2.3): мяч катится;
>
> 4) автокаузативное (см. п.2.4): бросился на врага;
>
> 5) взаимное (см. п.2.5): влюбленные целуются;
>
> 6) возвратно-каузативное (см. п.2.6): стрижется у парикмахера;
>
> 7) рефексивно-бенефактивное (см. п.2.7): запасся дровами;
>
> 8) объектно-имперсональное (см. п.2.8): собака кусается;
>
> 9) модально-пассивное (см. п.2.9): дверь не открывается;
>
> 10) безлично-пассивное (см. п.2.10): в работе на это указывается;
>
> 11) безличное модально-пассивное (см. п.2.11): мне не спится.

Я сейчас не хочу разбираться со всеми такими типами, но, похоже, только два или три из них позволяют образовывать причастия по смыслу близкие к пассивным формам на "-мый". Ваш пример попадает в группу "2) пассивное". И вот только на этом небольшом множестве - да при условии существования обеих форм -  ваша постановка вопроса имеет смысл. А попробуйте-ка от остальных образовать такие формы. Если даже и получится, значения будут настолько очевидно далекими, что разговор о каких-то семантических акцентах просто будет лишен смысла.

Но даже и на этом небольшом подмножестве пар причастий ваша гипотеза не слишком убедительна.

Я думаю, если вы наберете статистику из хотя бы двух-трех десятков подобных пар причастий, вы сами убедитесь, что ***какого-то единого правила, описывающего разницу в семантике членов этих пар, просто не существует***.

Comment: 1) "Планирующаяся руководством" — подобные конструкции уместны? @Niemand утверждает, что это "плохой русский язык".

Comment: 2) _Умывающийся (мылом) подросток - умываемый (мылом) подросток. Разница есть. Но совсем не та, что вы декларировали._ У глагола "умываться" другой тип семантический тип возвратного глагола: рефлексивный, а не пассивный, согласно приведённой вами классификации.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко C Niemand'ом сами разбирайтесь, тут у каждого свои тараканы. Возможно, что в коком-то контексте  "планируемый" будет стилистически предпочтительным вариантом, но в целом ничего "плохого" в такой форме не вижу.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко *У глагола "умываться" другой тип семантический тип возвратного глагола* - совершенно верно. Я вам и сказал, что ваши гипотезы, как и вообще подобную постановку вопроса, имеют смысл только на очень небольшом множестве возвратных причастий.  Мой пример - тому подтверждение.

Comment: Согласен. Вы ещё написали: _Планируемая к производству модель vs Планирующаяся к производству модель - вы видите разницу, кроме, возможно, стилистической?!_. Какую стилистическую разницу вы подразумеваете?

Answer (score 1):

Конструкции с глаголом "планироваться" образуют страдательный залог. Пример: "Проект планируется инженерами".

Gramma.ru пишет:

> Важнейшим грамматическим показателем страдательного залога является творительный падеж существительного со значением деятеля, реального субъекта действия. Отсутствие такого творительного падежа сближает страдательное значение глагола со средневозвратным, особенно в том случае, когда подлежащим является название лица (ср.: Лыжники отправляются в поход; Письма отправляются по почте; Посылки отправляются экспедитором)". Источник: http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=2.25.

Средневозвратный залог выражает действие субъекта, не переходящее на прямой объект, а как бы возвращающееся к самому субъекту, сосредоточенное в нем; ср.: возвращать книгу и возвращаться (самому), сосредоточить внимание и сосредоточиться (самому).

Таким образом, я предполагаю, что **в случае действительного причастия "планирующийся"**, употреблённого без субъекта в творительном падеже (т.е. не "Проект, планирующийся инженерами, скоро будет запущен", а "Планирующийся проект скоро будет запущен"), **семантический акцент ставится на внутреннем свойстве, признаке (сближение со средневозвратным значением)**.

**В случае страдательного причастия "планируемый" семантический акцент ставится на пассивности, на том, что объект подвергается действию (планированию), выраженному глаголом в форме причастия.**

"Планирующийся проект скоро будет запущен" — свойством проекта является то, что он в данный момент планируется.

"Планируемый проект скоро будет запущен" — просто указание на то, что это проект, который планируют.

Если моё чувство языка и знание грамматики меня подводят, исправьте меня.

Comment: >> Проект, *планирующийся инженерами*, скоро будет запущен – это есть всего-навсего плохой русский язык, а не "семантический акцент". Разумеется, "проект, планируемый инженерами".

Comment: Между прочим, "планируемый проект" (не говоря уж о планиру**ющемся**) – тоже сказано плоховато. Плеоназм.

Answer (score 1):

**В чём семантическое различие между планирующийся и планируемый?**

Я считаю, что некоторая разница есть, хотя и незначительная. Вероятно, во всех случаях эти слова взаимозаменяемы, но "планирующийся" подходит лучше по значению в контексте "предполагаемый, намечаемый" (в общих чертах), чем в контексте чётко размеченного плана.

Тонкие семантические различия между синонимами находить довольно сложно. С этой целью составляются объяснительные словари синонимов (напр., словарь Апресяна), и каждый может прочитать любую статью такого словаря, чтобы убедиться, насколько сложно бывает осознать даже самые явные отличия.

**Дополнение**. Добавил цитат из добротных источников. Таких цитат поиск находит сотни.

> ...Планирующийся в ближайшие годы международный эксперимент «ПолиМОДЕ»
>   ("Вестник Академии наук СССР", 1974)
>
> ...Рост культурного и профессионального уровня трудящихся,
>   планирующийся в условиях социализма (А.И. Арнольдов, "Культура
>   развитого социализма")
>
> Планирующийся в Брукхейвенской лаборатории эксперимент ("Реферативный
>   журнал: Физика", Изд-во Академии наук СССР, 1987)
>
> ...Не имело такого мощного производственного потенциала, как
>   планирующийся на 1981 — 1985 гг. ("Преподавание истории в школе",
>   1981)

Comment: Единственный пример из Нацкорпуса: «ОСП Новгородский почтамт просит Вас согласовать планирующиеся к закрытию в третьем квартале 2013 года отделения почтовой связи...  «Новгородские ведомости», 2013]. Планировать к закрытию - планирующиеся к закрытию (сохранение в причастии зависимого слова). Канцелярское  терминологическое сочетание? Больше примеров нет.

Comment: *Больше примеров нет.* — Я дополнил пример несколькими цитатами. Я подскажу, как пользоваться поиском в сети. Нужно набрать фрагмент текста в Гугле (в кавычках, чтобы было полное совпадение) и выбрать в верхнем меню поиска (под поисковой строкой) "Ещё\Книги". Затем можно бегло просматривать сотни цитат и выбирать только те из них, которые заслуживают доверия в Вашем понимании. Для надёжности я обычно перехожу на скан-копию страницы книги, чтобы убедиться наверняка.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию о поиске в сети. И пожалуйста, извините меня еще раз (надеюсь, последний), но приведенные примеры  МНЕ кажутся откровенно неграмотными. Планирующийся в ближайшие годы - это запланированный на ближайшие годы. Планирующийся в условиях социализма: планировать в условиях социализма - это составлять план в условиях социализма, то есть зависимое слово относится к глаголу, а не определяет предмет. Вот почему я предпочитаю пользоваться Нацкорпусом, он в плане речевой грамотности надежнее.

Comment: @Ксения Простите, что не могу согласиться с Вами. Вы вправе иметь свою точку зрения по вопросам грамотности и правильности. Благодаря противоборству таких мнений и развивается язык. Но я в этой жизни уже определился с кругом авторитетных для меня источников. Я могу поверить в наличие одной-двух однотипных ошибок в добротных изданиях, но их не может быть сотни и тысячи. Распространённые ошибки разбираются в статьях и монографиях, их изучают в учебниках, отмечают в словарях и т. п. Но в данном случае ничего этого нет.

Comment: А мне кажется, что не стоит всегда следовать авторитетам и иметь в чем-либо постоянное мнение. Статичность, отсутствие движения и перемен – это признак отсутствия жизни. Помните, как  у Тургенева:  –...Аркадий Николаич сейчас сказывал, что вы не признаете никаких авторитетов? Не верите им? – Да зачем же я стану их признавать? И чему я буду верить? Мне скажут дело, я соглашаюсь, вот и все.

Comment: _..."Планирующийся" подходит лучше по значению в контексте "предполагаемый, намечаемый" (в общих чертах), чем в контексте чётко размеченного плана_ — вы имеете в виду, что первое лучше употреблять для словарного значения "включать в план каких-н. работ, предполагать устройство чего-н", а второе — для значения "составлять план развития чего-н."?

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле вопрос не особо мудрёный.

Сравним более простую пару:
*Начинающийся.* || Который просто начинается. Характеристика. Причастие в качестве прилагательного.
*Начинаемый.* || Который начинается **кем-то**. Причастие. Акцент на **субъекте** действия — что кто-то начинает.

Ср.:
*Завершающееся точкой предложение.

Произведение, завершаемое соавтором.*

Такая же разница между *планирующийся* и *планируемый* и всеми похожими парами.

Оптимальное применение в плане стилистики:
*планирующееся на завтра совещание;

планируемое председателем совещание*.

Answer (score 0):

Корректная форма: планируемый. В Нацкорпусе: планируемый – 47 примеров, планирующийся – 0 примеров)

1) В русском языке существует два залога: пассивный (действие совершается над предметом) и возвратный (действие переходит на действующий предмет или как-то связано с ним): кошка умывается, крапива жжется, дети смеются и т.д..

2) Глагол "планировать" имеет два значения: а) составлять план; б) предполагать какое-либо действие.  Пассивный залог  – планироваться, например: Как планируются бюджетные расходы? Планируется строительство двух новых станций.

3) ПЛАНИРУЕМЫЙ. Как известно, формы на МЫЙ обычно являются прилагательными, так как страд. причастие настоящего времени обозначает признак предмета, на которым **в текущий момент** производится действие названным производителем действия в форме Т.п., а это случается не часто (пример: видимый мною объект – я его сейчас вижу).

В качестве прилагательного "планируемый" используется часто:  планируемые расходы, планируемый бюджет, планируемый срок окончания работ.  **Планируемый проект**? Это тавтология, потому что проект – это тоже план.

4) ПЛАНИРУЮЩИЙСЯ. Это причастная форма, которая  фонетически возможна, но семантически обычно некорректна (опять же обозначение признака предмета, который в настоящий момент совершает действие).

5) Вообще говоря, от глаголов в форме пассивного (не возвратного) залога причастия/прилагательные образуются редко. Мы говорим: изображаемая автором действительность, но не "изображающаяся автором действительность".  А вот от возвратных глаголов образование причастий/прилагательных возможно: смеющиеся дети, умывающаяся кошка.

Comment: *Планируемый проект? Это тавтология...* — или Вы не смогли подобрать подходящего контекста. "В нашей компании на следующий год запланированы три проекта по улучшению сервиса. Каждый из планируемых проектов очень важен для нас". Здесь нет тавтологии: есть внутренний план каждого проекта и внешний (мета-) план, объединяющий эти проекты. Подобное имеется в виду, когда говорят о планируемом проекте (даже если он один).

Comment: ПРОЕКТ, -а; м. [от лат. projectus - выступающий вперёд] 1.  Разработанный план сооружения, постройки, изготовления или реконструкции чего-л.  Это первое и основное значение слова. Я слышу здесь "планируемый план", но не исключаю, что оно может применяться и даже имеет какой-то смысл. Но я бы не стала так говорить.

Comment: Понятно. Лучше предупреждать, что Вы ограничили себя одним значением слова (пусть даже основным). В следующей цитате из Л.Н. Гумилёва имеется в виду другое значение: "**Планируемый проект** рассчитан на три года и имеет целью проследить и осветить этнографические аспекты..."

Comment: Я допускаю, что тавтология может превратиться в терминологическое выражение, возможно,  оно даже будет удобным и нужным, вот только  не надо искать там корректную грамматику и правильную русскую речь.  Впрочем,  пока в Нацкорусе "планируемый проект" еще не появился.

Comment: Вы вправе видеть тавтологию где угодно, это вовсе не означает, что она там есть. Хотите, я Вам ещё цитат набросаю (из авторитетных источников)? Вы только скажите, где "нужно искать правильную русскую речь". И уточните, пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть цитата выше без "тавтологии".

Comment: Извините,  я, наверное, не учла особый статус этого форума, где всё надо доказывать, даже свое личное мнение по поводу любого вопроса (впредь буду осторожнее).Но вот тавтология не математика,  там тонкая грань между речевой ошибкой и  речевым приемом.

Comment: _Как известно, формы на МЫЙ обычно являются прилагательными_ — откуда вы взяли? Иногда встречается дополнительное адъективное значение, как в случаях с "видимый", но в основном на "-мый" причастия. Таким образом, "планируемый" является причастием даже без указания производителя в форме Т. п.

Comment: А вы откуда это взяли (если спросить так же "вежливо", как вы)? Я - вот отсюда: "Причастиями они (слова на-мый) являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется творительный действующего лица, реже — творительный орудия: не любимый матерью ребёнок; движение, не тормозимое воздухом. При наличии других пояснительных слов мы имеем дело с прилагательными на -мый (они теряют значения страдательности и приобретают качественное значение): п.14. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

Comment: @Sharon Был неправ. Получается, без зависимых слов слова на ‑мый всегда прилагательные, а не причастия? _Вы сможете добавить доступный канал в создаваемый рекламный блок или же создать новый канал_. "Создаваемый" — прилагательное?

Comment: Это прилагательное. Страдательное причастие настоящего времени обозначает такое действие-признак, которое совпадает по времени с действием глагола-сказуемого.  Вот пример: "Как часто по брегам твоим Бродил я тихий и туманный, Заветным умыслом". томим